# Uploading files to an Amazon S3 bucket using flask Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file using the flask and boto3 module to one of my Amazon S3 buckets. My code does not just upload the file, but it also uploads the folder where that file is stored. Can somebody please help me with that. If I am already providing the path of the file in the code which you can see below. How does the upload thing work in the Html button?

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST'])
def upload():
if request.method == "POST":
    f = request.files['file']
    f.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, f.filename))
    upload_file(f"readme/{f.filename}", BUCKET)

    return redirect("/storage")
```

Answer (score 0):

Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. If you upload a file to a folder, the folder will magically 'appear'. Later, if you delete all files in the (pretend) folder, then the folder will disappear.

If you use the "Create Folder" button in the S3 management console, it actually creates a zero-length object with the same name of the folder. This 'forces' the folder to appear because it contains an object (but that object isn't displayed).

So, when you say "it also uploads the folder where that file is stored", you are probably just seeing the folder name 'appear'. It probably only uploaded one file.